# Cucumber: retry failed scenarios immediatly

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I read about the solutions to write the failed scenarios to an rerun.txt and execute them later.

I wonder, if there is another way to repeat a scenario immediately.

My system under test sometimes has temporary problems, but the very next test runs successful.
I can detect these temporary problems while my testexecution inside a stepdefinition-method or in the @after-method and would like to retry the current scenario immediately one more time.

Offers Cucumber a way to do this?
Or can some tell, that there is no way and I should use the rerun.txt-solution?

Bye Jochen